# Symfony 1.4.2 no content in PHP cURL PUT request

Tags: php, curl, symfony-1.4, put

Using PHP cURL and Symfony 1.4.2

I'm trying to do a PUT request including data (JSON) to modify an object in my REST web services, but can't catch the data on the server side.

It seems that the content is attached successfully when checking at my logs:

```
PUT to http://localhost:8080/apiapp_test.php/v1/reports/498 with post body content=%7B%22report%22%3A%7B%22title%22%3A%22The+title+has+been+updated%22%7D%7D
```

I attached the data like this:

```
$curl_opts = array(
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array('content' => $post_data)),
);
```

And wanted to get the data using something like this

```
$payload = $request->getPostParameter('content');
```

It is not working and I've tried many ways to get this data in my actions file.
I've tried the following solutions:

```
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $post_vars);
$payload = $post_vars['content'];
// or
$data = $request->getContent(); // $request => sfWebRequest
$payload = $data['content'];
// or
$payload = $request->getPostParameter('content');

// then I'd like to do that
$json_array = json_decode($payload, true);
```

I just don't know how to get this data in my actions and it's frustrating, I've read many topics here about it but none is working for me.

Additional informations:

I have these setup for my cURL request:

```
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $http_method);

if ($http_method === sfRequest::PUT) {
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
    $content_length = array_key_exists(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_options) ? strlen($curl_options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS]) : 0;
    $curl_options[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER][] = 'Content-Length: ' . $content_length;
}

curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 4);
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, true);
curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

In sfWebRequest.php, I've seen this:

```
case 'PUT':
  $this->setMethod(self::PUT);
  if ('application/x-www-form-urlencoded' === $this->getContentType())
  {
    parse_str($this->getContent(), $postParameters);
  }
  break;
```

So I tried to set the header's Content-Type to it but it doesn't do anything.

If you have any idea, please help!

Comment: `$request->getPostParameter()` will not work when you are using PUT HTTP method. `file_get_contents("php://input")` seems to be the proper way to do this. Just check what exactly do you get after reading the input (I'm not sure if `parse_str` will work here). Or you can always switch to POST if the method isn't that important.

Comment: I've tried to only print `file_get_contents("php://input")` and this is empty. I've tried using `$request->getPostParameter()` because in sfWebRequest.php there a line adding the content to the post parameters (see above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [an other question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3958226/569101), I've tested this solution and I got the correct result:

```
$body = 'the RAW data string I want to send';

/** use a max of 256KB of RAM before going to disk */
$fp = fopen('php://temp/maxmemory:256000', 'w');
if (!$fp) {
    die('could not open temp memory data');
}
fwrite($fp, $body);
fseek($fp, 0);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp); // file pointer
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, strlen($body));

$output = curl_exec($ch);

echo $output;
die();
```

And on the other side, you can retrieve the content using:

```
$content = $request->getContent();
```

If you `var_dump` it, you will retrieve:

> the RAW data string I want to send

Comment: Thanks for helping! `$output` contains the raw JSON file, what I'd like to get on the other side. However, `$content = $request->getContent();` does not retrieve the content, it's empty there.

Comment: If `$output` contains the raw JSON it's because the other side var_dump it. You see?

Comment: That's exactly what I thought, if I get the response with the content it means it's was somewhere in the request (but can't get it). Digging into it...

Comment: Made it work with an external API, able to receive the content successfully. I guess there's something in our API locally that is messed up. Thanks!