# How to perform a PUT operation using CURL in PHP?

Tags: php, web-services, rest, curl, put

I would like to perform a PUT operation on a webservice using CURL. Let's assume that:

webservice url: http://stageapi.myprepaid.co.za/api/ConsumerRegisterRequest/cac52674-1711-e311-b4a8-00155d4905d3

municipality= NMBM 
sgc= 12345

I've written the code below, but it outputs this error message: "ExceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". Any help would be so much appreciated. Thanks!

```
<?php
function sendJSONRequest($url, $data)
{             
    $data_string = json_encode($data);
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);               
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                       
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Accept: application/json',
        'X-MP-Version: 10072013')                      
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    ob_start();
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    if ($result === false || $info['http_code'] == 400) {
      return $result;
    } else {
      return $result;
    }
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close($ch);
}

$mun = $_GET['municipality'];
$sgc = $_GET['sgc'];
$req = $_GET['req']; //cac52674-1711-e311-b4a8-00155d4905d3

//myPrepaid PUT URL
echo $mpurl = "http://stageapi.myprepaid.co.za/api/ConsumerRegisterRequest/$req";

// Set Variables
$data = array("Municipality" => "$mun", "SGC" => "$sgc");

//Get Response
echo $response = sendJSONRequest($mpurl, $data);

?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using PUT method with PHP cUrl Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958226/using-put-method-with-php-curl-library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code, but changed it so it pointed at a very basic HTTP server on my localhost. Your code is working correctly, and making the following request:

```
PUT /api/ConsumerRegisterRequest/cac52674-1711-e311-b4a8-00155d4905d3 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9420
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
X-MP-Version: 10072013
Content-Length: 37

{"Municipality":"NMBM","SGC":"12345"}
```

The error message you're receiving is coming from the `stageapi.myprepaid.co.za` server. This is the full response when I point it back to them:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 30 Aug 2013 04:30:41 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 867

{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException","StackTrace":"   at MyPrepaidApi.Controllers.ConsumerRegisterRequestController.Put(CrmRegisterRequest value) in c:\\Workspace\\MyPrepaid\\Prepaid Vending System\\PrepaidCloud\\WebApi\\Controllers\\ConsumerRegisterRequestController.cs:line 190\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass13.<GetExecutor>b__c(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}
```

You may want to check out the API to make sure you're passing them the correct information. If you are, the problem could be on their end.

And while I realize this isn't part of your question and this is in development, please remember to sanitize any data from `$_GET`. :)

Comment: Thanks. I do think that the code is working correctly. I've tried a different coding and it still gave me the afore-mentioned error message. Maybe there's really something wrong in the webservice's end.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
```

Comment: I've tried using this already but it still didn't work. Thanks anyway. :)